# transforming logs into average number of users per day

Tags: sql, logging, group-by, google-bigquery, average

I am trying to transform logs into average number of sessions per week day or per hour

I have a table looking like

> user_id|session_id|session_start_time|fleet_name

and I want to have a table looking like this

> fleet|weekday/hour|avg(count(session_id)

I am using bigquery o do so to push the data into datastudio. The goal would be to show the number of connection on average on a given fleet on a monday or at 8 am

```
SELECT fleet_name,extract(dayofweek from date) as day, avg(count_user) 
FROM( SELECT extract(date from session_start_time) as date,
          COUNT(user_id)as count_user,fleet_name
      FROM `gbl-ist-ve-aws-appstream-costs.appstream_dataset.log_sessions`
      group by date,fleet_name)
group by fleet_name, day
```

the issue I am having with the code bellow is that it is ignoring the day/hour when no one connects thus the average is wrong. I have seen some answers on similar issue with inner join but I don't have another table with the day/hour per fleet, should I create one. 
I was also thinking of dividing the total count per number of weekday or hours (number of mondays) between two dates but that might be a twisted way to proceed...

Any help would be valuable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was also thinking of dividing the total count per number of weekday or hours (number of mondays) between two dates but that might be a twisted way to proceed...

I think this might actually be a good idea!
Below is example to illustrate

```
#standardSQL
SELECT fleet_name, EXTRACT(dayofweek FROM DATE) AS day, 
  SUM(count_user) / (DATE_DIFF(MAX(DATE), MIN(DATE), WEEK) + 1)
FROM( SELECT EXTRACT(DATE FROM session_start_time) AS DATE,
          COUNT(user_id) AS count_user,fleet_name
      FROM `gbl-ist-ve-aws-appstream-costs.appstream_dataset.log_sessions`
      GROUP BY DATE,fleet_name)
GROUP BY fleet_name, day
```

Take a look at `SUM(count_user) / (DATE_DIFF(MAX(DATE), MIN(DATE), WEEK) + 1)` - this is replacement for `avg(count_user)`. I did quick test against dummy data and looks to me it works

As you can see, I assume your query conceptually correct so, I am not changing anything else

Comment: Hello, thank you very much it is working as expected but there is something I did not consider: it is picking as max and min (date) the first/last time a user was connected so the number of week is sometime wrong:
Exemple fleet exist since Week 1 but no one connected on a thursday until week 3 and after week 6 we are now week 9 it should have been 9 weeks but it is showing 3.  I could try to pick the min for all existing fleet but it would be wrong because some fleets are older than other. I'll change max(date) by current date, and I think it'll be a good approximation Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, if on 5 consecutive Mondays (for example), you are seeing user counts of 10, 10 , 0, 10, 10.  You are expecting the average to be 8, but your inner sub-query only returns 4 tens, and you are seeing an average of 10?

To solve this, I would generate a date array and left join your data onto that.  This will ensure that every date has a count, even if it is 0.  You will then need to incorporate the 0s into your average.

```
with calendar as (
  SELECT date 
  FROM UNNEST( GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(DATE('2019-06-01'), CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) ) AS date
),
daily_counts as (
  SELECT 
    fleet_name, 
    extract(date from session_start_time) as date,
    COUNT(user_id)as count_user
  FROM <table>
  group by 1,2
)
select
  fleet_name,
  date,
  avg( ifnull(count_user,0) ) as avg_daily_user_count
from calendar
left join daily_counts using(date)
group by 1,2
```

Comment: Hello,
you understood correctly
we are getting close but this is creating a table with the date when I wanted a table with dayofweek I'll try to modifiy you query to get this. I'll keep you updated thank you for your help

Comment: so I just changed the end of the query
select
  fleet_name,
  extract(dayofweek from date) as day,
  avg( ifnull(count_user,0) ) as avg_daily_user_count
from calendar
left join daily_counts using(date)
group by 1,2

it is now working thank you :)